# How to populate classes needed for a web service

Tags: c#

I need to call a web service that accepts a class structure as input. The class itself is made up of regular field types plus one or more instances of a subclass. I was given example code that populates the class, but with static data. I need to populate it with dynamic data from user input at runtime and am not certain of the correct method to populate the subclass (PaymentProposalDetail) with 1 or more sets of data.

Here is the static data provided as an example:

```
            PaymentApproval pa = new PaymentApproval()
            {
                VendorId = "14771",
                Company = "333-TTTT",
                PaymentApprovalNumber = "12345678",
                SubmissioNDate = DateTime.Today,
                ValueDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1),
                TotalAmount = 200000.00,
                PaymentInstructionId = "ABCDEFGH",
                Currency = "USD"
                Comment = ""
            };
            pa.Details = new PaymentProposalDetail[] {
                new PaymentProposalDetail()
                {
                    InvoiceNumber = "1234567",
                    PayAmount = 454880.46,
                    InvoiceCurrency = "USD"
                },
                new PaymentProposalDetail()
                {
                    InvoiceNumber = "9876543",
                    PayAmount = 543340.67,
                    InvoiceCurrency = "USD"
                }
            };
```

The class definitions:

```
public partial class PaymentApproval : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{
    private string BankIdField;
    private string CommentField;
    private string CompanyField;
    private string CurrencyField;
    private PaymentProposalDetail[] DetailsField;
    private string PaymentApprovalNumberField;
    private string PaymentInstructionIdField;
    private System.DateTime SubmissioNDateField;
    private decimal TotalAmountField;
    private System.DateTime ValueDateField;
    private string VendorIdField;
}

public partial class PaymentProposalDetail : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{
    private string InvoiceCurrencyField;
    private string InvoiceNumberField;
    private decimal PayAmountField;
}
```

I guess I need to build an array of PaymentProposalDetail objects within my loop that is getting the data from the UI. So for each set of data I do

```
PaymentApproval pa;
/* populate regular fields in pa */
foreach (data UIdata in UIdataStruct)
{
    PaymentProposalDetail pd = new PaymentProposalDetail();
    pd.InvoiceNumber = UIdata.invoiceNumber;
    pd.PayAmount = UIdata.payAmount;
    pd.InvoiceCurrenct = UIdata.invoiceCurrency;
}
```

But then how do I add pd to pa.Details?

Comment: depends on the system you're building \ medium your using, but would suggest model binding to get your information from UI to code \ backend

Comment: how do you want the user to input it?

Comment: @DanielA.White the data is coming from a UI which I can get to. The data for PaymentProposalDetail is retrieved in a foreach loop through the UI's data structure. The part I am having issue with is which of the classes need to be allocated before populating and how to do so.

Comment: Added more detail to OP

Answer (score 0):

Add each `PaymentProposalDetail` item to a collection and assign it to the `PaymentApproval`.

```
PaymentApproval pa;
/* populate regular fields in pa */

List<PaymentProposalDetail> details = new List<PaymentProposalDetail>();

foreach (data UIdata in UIdataStruct)
{
    PaymentProposalDetail pd = new PaymentProposalDetail();
    pd.InvoiceNumber = UIdata.invoiceNumber;
    pd.PayAmount = UIdata.payAmount;
    pd.InvoiceCurrenct = UIdata.invoiceCurrency;

    details.Add(pd);
}

pa.Details = details.ToArray();
```